# Using PKCS#12 file with Tomcat 8.5.41 Nio2 connector

Tags: tomcat, openssl, pkcs#12

3rd party Docker image I have to use has Tomcat 8.5.41, OpenSSL 1.1.0j. Tomcat log indicates OpenSSL successfully initialized.

Issue is that Tomcat is not successful at initializing the `[Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol-8443]]`
I've added this Connector element to the server.xml being used by the Tomcat process:

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
            maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
            scheme="https" secure="true" defaultSSLHostConfigName="thehost"
            sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
            keyPass="changeIt"
            keystorePass="changeIt"
            keystoreType="PKCS12"
            keystoreFile="conf/thehost-cert.pfx" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig certificateVerification="none" protocols="SSLv2Hello,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"
                hostName="thehost"
                ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
                caCertificateFile="ISRG_Root_X1.pem"  caCertificatePath="/etc/ssl/certs">
            <OpenSSLConf>
            </OpenSSLConf>
            <Certificate type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

The server certificate is a PKCS#12 obtained by *The Littlest JupyterHub* ACME setup. So I really would like to use that cert to avoid a browser having to deal with multiple certs (different serial#s, etc) even if issued by the same Root CA. I did find that I had to recreate the PKCS#12 file to add a password (a Stackoverflow posting indicated Tomcat won't accept an empty keystore password. Hence recreating.

I've tried using the non-deprecated config elements (had the keystorePass attribute in the Certificate element via certificateKeystorePassword but not allows as that's a JSSE attribute) but no luck - the password is wrong.  I've used the container's openssl pkcs12 command to verify the password is correct. Any other values -> failure to display the cert & key in PEM format.

Has anyone gotten the 8.5+ syntax to work with a PKCS#12 file that has a password, with OpenSSL 1.1.0 usage? With the Nio2 connector?  And of course, moving these attributes around, now I get the very pleasant "IllegalArgumentException" with no indication in the exception identifying what illegal argument? Did I mention how much fun this is?

MTIA for any insights. Best decision might to scrape the certs, key from the pfx & use traditional PEM x509 cert, private key files? As I've done that plenty in the past 15+ years. PKCS#12 files? not so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix Connector-level and SSLHostConfig/Certificate-level attributes like that; see [para 6 here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support).

I don't have 8.5 to hand, but in 9.0.16 (with tcnative 1.2.21 and OpenSSL 1.1.1) on Ubuntu 18.04, which has supposedly the same config (but differences at app level) it works for me if I follow the doc and either use *all* Connector-level attributes (i.e. the old pre-8.5 way, now deprecated but still working) *or* use all SSLHostConfig and Certificate *and* have SSLHostConfig.hostName match Connector.defaultSSLHostConfigName (which yours doesn't):

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
    maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
     keyPass="redacted" keystorePass="redacted" keystoreType="PKCS12"
     keystoreFile="redacted.p12" 
     sslEnabledProtocols="SSLv2Hello,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"
     ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
    >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
 >
```

or

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
    maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
    defaultSSLHostConfigName="localhost"
    >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig hostName="localhost"
        protocols="SSLv2Hello,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"
        ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
        >
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreType="PKCS12" 
            certificateKeystorePassword="redacted" certificateKeyPassword="redacted"
            certificateKeystoreFile="redacted" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Aside: OpenSSL 1.1.0 doesn't support TLS 1.3, and specifying SSLv2Hello with OpenSSL is ignored as stated in the doc, and even for JSSE specifying SSLv2Hello with *only* 1.2 and/or 1.3 makes no sense, because even in the long-gone days when it had some utility SSLv2Hello can't negotiate protocols requiring extensions -- which both 1.2 (effectively) and 1.3 do. Also it's unnecesary and useless to specify 'ca' certs (in OpenSSL style) or 'trustStore' certs (in JSSE style) when you're not doing client authentication.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your answer. I had saved a version of server.xml hours before posting, one that had all the ssl options out of the connector per para 6, and that had the Connector.defaultSSLHostConfigName attr set. But, of course I had a typo - the 2 values for the actual hostname were not matching -> neither the SSLHostConfig or its Certificate element would be used. Are those values used only to match a SSLHostConfig element as the default? So I went back to trying. Stripped out stuff per your feedback.  "Keystore password was incorrect". Weird as openssl pkcs12 within container accepts it.

Comment: @Steven: SSLHostConfig.hostname values are (also) used to select which entry (and thus cert-and-key or set of them) is used for each connection, based on SNI, if there are multiple SSLHostConfig elements aka 'virtual hosts', which you don't have. Re "password was incorrect": (1) does it contain any non-ASCII characters? Those may be handled differently by Java than by other software including OpenSSL (2) try `keytool -importkeystore -v -srckeystore yourfile -destkeystore junkfile` and if (your) Java has a problem that should give a full stacktrace